# Como se pronuncia "pregar" (sermões) e "pregar" (pregos, sustos) no Brasil?

Tags: português-brasileiro, ortografia, pronúncia

Trata-se de dois verbos diferentes, e pelo menos em Portugal são pronunciados de formas diferentes:

- [***Pregar* ³** (Michaelis)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/palavra/138x0/pregar%3CEi%3E3%3C/Ei%3E/) sermões (do latim *praedicare*) tem  o **e** aberto como em *fé*: pr[ɛ]gar.
- [***Pregar* ¹** (Michaelis)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/pregar/) pregos, bofetões, sustos ou partidas (do latim *plicare*, segundo o Houaiss), tem  o **e** quase inaudível: pr[ɨ]gar; praticamente /pɾgaɾ/; este fonema [ɨ] não existe no português brasileiro; podem ouvi-lo na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio) (no centro do topo da figura).

Não há diferença quando o **e** é tónico: *eu pr[ɛ]go um sermão ou um prego*. Mas há sempre que o **e** é átono: *nós pr[ɛ]gamos um sermão*,  mas *pr[ɨ]gamos um prego*.

Isto é em Portugal, e a pergunta é: **como é que é no Brasil?**

A dúvida surgiu-me quando li em *Música ao Longe* do Érico Veríssimo (7ª ed, Livraria do Globo, Porto Alegre, 1945, p. 20; negrito meu):

> Estamos a primeiro de abril. Dia dos bobos. Tia Cleonice gritou que mamãe estava me chamando. Fui e vi que era um primeiro de abril que ela tinha me **prègado**.

Ora eu interpreto o acento grave em “prègado” como indicando que o timbre é aberto e que haveria outro *pregar* com **e** não aberto. Nunca vi acento grave em **e** (ou **a** ou **o**) que não fosse aberto, e alguns autores usaram-no precisamente “para denotar que *a, e, o* átonos são abertos, quando haja homógrafos em que êles sejam surdos” [(Gonçaves Viana, 1912)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Q-U6XfAyC04C&q=pregar&dq=pregar&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq0LKQue7jAhUit3EKHfjhDxoQ6AEIWDAH).

Mas todos os dicionários indicam que o *pregar* de partidas com as do primeiro de abril é o *pregar* dos pregos, pontapés e sustos ([Michaelis 8](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/pregar/), ([Aulete 4](http://www.aulete.com.br/pregar)), que em Portugal é o que não tem timbre aberto. **Então e no Brasil como é:**

- **Qual é a pronúncia dos vários *pregares*?**
- **Qual seria a explicação possível para o acento grave no “prègado” do Érico Veríssimo?**

Comment: Ui. Acho que sinto como válidos tanto "ele pr/é/gava sermões" como ele "pr/e/gava sermões". Estas perguntas dão-me nós no miolo.

Comment: @ANeves, mas não "pr/é/gavas" um prego, ou pr/é/gavas"? O [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/pregar) também diz que se pronuncia com **e** aberto (2ª *pregar*)

Comment: Não, não *pr/é/gava um pr/é/go.

Comment: [1. Pronúncia brasileira de pregar peça](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=equVfUwZebA&feature=youtu.be&t=32); [2. Pronúncia brasileira de pregar prego](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpKU8cgQoMw&feature=youtu.be&t=99).

Comment: @ANeves, então e S. António *prègou* ao peixes, ou *prgou*, ou tanto faz? E as testemunhas de Jeová andam a *prègar* ou a *prgar* ?

Comment: @Pedro, pois, é "prêgar" nesse dois casos. Já tinha imaginado. Esses em Portugal são com [ɨ], que normalmente corresponde ao [ê] ou [i] no Brasil: *s[ê]nhora* ou *s[i]nhora*; e como eu não me parecia que fosse *pr[i]gar*...

Comment: Jacinto, «para mim tanto me faz»; eu diria *prègou*, mas não estranharia *prgou*.

Comment: @ANeves, pois, é que houve uma espécie de convergência semântica: ninguém diz "prègar" um prego, susto, ou raspanete; mas diz-se "prègar" sermões (tipo, na missa); mas figuradamente, *sermão* também é 'raspanete'! Mas eu estranharia ouvir "S. António 'prgou' aos peixes" ou " 'prgar' no deserto".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vivência pessoal sem referências.

Eu, nativo do sudeste brasileiro, tendo passado por dezenas de primeiros de abril, nunca percebi alguma diferença na pronuncia dos dois verbos. Pronuncio os dois da mesma forma, com o "e" fechado. E acredito que mesmo no Nordeste, onde o "e" é pronunciado bem aberto, os dois verbos sejam pronunciados da mesma forma, isto é, com o "e" aberto.

Embora alguns dicionários façam uma distinção entre a pronuncia dos dois verbos (pregador de roupas ou de pregos x pregador, aquele que faz pregações), acredito que pouca gente saiba disso e deve ser muito difícil ouvir "pregador" com o "e" aberto, exceto no Nordeste, onde até "Pernambuco" é pronunciado com o "e" aberto. Talvez os pregadores religiosos tenham conhecimento da diferença.  Quanto a mim, acho que nunca precisei ou precisarei usar essa palavra.

Quanto à grafia da palavra, não encontrei a forma com acento grave nos dicionários e acredito tratar-se de erro de impressão.

Comment: Também nativo e concordo plenamente.

Comment: Era mesmo a experiência nativa que eu queria. Portanto, decididamente (usando o acento só para indicar o timbre) é *prêgar* um primeiro de abril -- logo no livro só pode ter sido engano. Agora só para não deixar "nenhuma pedra por virar", tu dizes também"as testemunhas de Jeová andam prêgando" e "S. António prêgou aos peixes", não "prégando, prégou", certo? É que mesmo em Portugal creio que já ouvi *prgar um sermão*  (não *prégar*). Possivelmente porque com *sermão* houve uma convergência semântica: >>

Comment: *pregar* (de *praedicare*) um sermão; e *pregar* (de plicare) um prego, bofetada, primeiro de abril, repreensão; mas figuradamente, *sermão* também significa 'repreensão'. Só encontrarias *prègar*, se é que alguma vez se escreveu assim no Brasil, em dicionários antigos, anteriores a 1971 ou mesmo só anteriores a 1943.

Comment: @Jacinto   No Brasil, já ouvi algumas palavras da língua portuguesa serem pronunciadas de modo diferente do que a maioria da população pronuncia.  "Banana" é uma delas.  "Pego" em "ele foi pego" também.  Outras são as que têm a sílaba "gui" incluída, como "sanguíneo".  Com "pregar", "prega" e "pregador", no entanto, nunca ouvi uma pronuncia diferente da minha, seja qual for o significado.

Answer (score 3):

No Sul do Brasil:

- Pregar: ambos são com "e" fechado.
- Prego: ambos com "e" aberto.

É assim no Sul do Brasil. Já no Nordeste, devido diferenças no sotaque, creio que "pregar" seja com "e" aberto.

Comment: Mas pronunciam-se com **e** aberto (é) ou fechado (ê)? Tens alguma ideia por que é que o Érico Veríssimo escreveu "pr**è**gado"?

Comment: poderia ter sido um erro de digitação? Ou uma grafia antiga?

Comment: 'É' aberto. Grafia antiga com certeza (mas sem fontes hehe). Isso ocorreu com muitas palavras, como o "vós mi cê" que sumiu. Você está lendo algo antigo certo?

Comment: Melhorei a resposta pra evitar a confusão.

Comment: @Peixoto, já houve quem escrevesse *prègar*, mas só relativamente a sermões na missa, boas novas; mas *pregar* pregos vi sempre sem acento. É assim que estão os dois no [dicionário de Cândido Figueiredo de 1899](https://books.google.pt/books?id=OS9AAAAAYAAJ&q=%22pronunciar+declamando%22&dq=%22pronunciar+declamando%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiar-Wck_PjAhUeQUEAHeSbB5oQ6AEIXzAI) e também no de 1913 e 1939.

Comment: John, obrigado pela clarificação.

Comment: @Peixoto, mas o Cândido de Figueiredo era português.

Comment: @Jacinto, acento e aberto e fechado é algo que já não entedia, depois de chegar em portugal e ver António (ao invés de Antônio, como é escrito no Brasil), me confundiu mais ainda....

Comment: No sudeste (Rio de Janeiro) também é assim.